# Boto3 - Copying File from S3 to Lightsail

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-lightsail

I have a requirement to copy the file as soon as it landed in the S3 bucket. So I enabled trigger to lambda function on S3. But I am not sure how to copy the content to **lightsail** directory using AWS lambda. I looked into the documentation but I don't see any solution using Python - Boto3.

I can only see the FTP solution. Is there any other way to dump the file into Lightsail from S3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for ec2 instances you [SSM Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) for that.

In this solution, your lambda invokes sends a command (e.g. download some files from s3) to the instance by means of the SSM Run Command.

For this to work, you need to install **SSM Agent on your Lightsail Instance**. The following link describs the installation process:

- [Configuring SSM Agent on an Amazon Lightsail Instance](https://cloudbriefly.com/post/configuring-ssm-agent-on-an-amazon-lightsail-instance/#how-to-run-shell-commands-on-a-managed-instance).

The link also gives an example of sending commands to the instance:

- [How to Run Shell Commands on a Managed Instance](https://cloudbriefly.com/post/configuring-ssm-agent-on-an-amazon-lightsail-instance/#how-to-run-shell-commands-on-a-managed-instance)

Comment: Is it a feasible solution when we are talking about a million requests per month?

Comment: @petereg157 I woudn't worry about Run Command. I think the issue  can be whether your instances handle so much downloading files? Connecting to s3, downloading from s3 takes time. Even if all these operations take 1 second, you taking about 277h of constant downloading from s3 per month.